# dependent variable is not normal distribution, what's the best linear model I should use?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model

I am building a predictive model for a company to predict counter party default risk.

In a linear format, it looks like y = bX

where X is around 50 independent variables, such as income, age, sex, years-of-education etc

where y is either the profit we can make from the interest payment, or the loss of the principal when the counter party really goes default.

Since counter parties will normally be able to pay off their interest, the y is heavily skewed to positive. However, when one of the counter parties really went to default, we lose the principal, and that's much bigger than the interest.

So, the y vector contains a large number of +1 or +2, and a small fraction of large negative numbers like -10, -20, -50

I tried OLS and it seems to have some predicting power, but I have big concerns about y's distribution. I read from somewhere saying that linear model doesn't require y to be normal. If that's the case, why we need generalized linear model (GLM)?

can anyone clarify this a bit?

I will appreciate any comments here

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For a problem like this I would suggest modelling the defaults separately.

So you'd have a binary outcome default/non-default (logistic regression say)

and then a model for the non-defaults and one for the defaults. They might each be roughly (conditionally) gamma, say